# has_many :through causes error: HasManyThroughSourceAssociationMacroError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I need to assign students (users) to classes (studentclasses)

I have a simple many-to-many relationship using 3 tables:

**studentclasses** (lesson details)

**users**  (user... student info)

**studentclass_users** (Join table containing **user_id** and **studentclass_id**)

I'm using has_many :through and my models look like the following:

**studentclass.rb**

```
class Studentclass < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :studentclass_users
  has_many :users, :through => :studentclass_users
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    ...more here...

    has_many :studentclass_users
    has_many :studentclasses, :through => :studentclass_users
end
```

**studentclass_users.rb**

```
class StudentclassUsers < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :studentclass
  belongs_to :user
end
```

For testing purposes, I'm just using a hidden field in my studentclass new view partial to tack on a user id when creating the class and it is as follows:

**_new.html.erb**

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "studentclass[user_ids][]", 29%>
```

And in my studentclass controller:

**studentclasses_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @studentclass = Studentclass.new
end 

def create
  @studentclass = Studentclass.new(params[:studentclass])
  @studentclass.save!
end
```

My params comes back:

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MjBTf4rtcyo8inADrSxPZB3vLOKtlZRVFlQJJzfCqWs=", "studentclass"=>{"class_title"=>"hjhkj", "user_ids"=>["29"]}, "commit"=>"Save"}

which seems fine but I get the following error:

> NameError (uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationMacroError):

I think this is something simple with naming maybe?  Any help would be appreciated